# CRM 2013: Add record to related section

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

I have an issue with crm 2013. I use fetchXML for filtered (for example) Billing Account. 
When our team work with CRM 2011 all working fine, but we migrate to CRM 2013 and have a problem with add related Project.

```
retrieveRecord( 
                recordId,
                "xxx_project",
                null,
                null,
                function (result) {
                    var xId = (result.xxx_Customer) ? result.xxx_xCustomer : "";

                    // Fetch to retrieve filtered data.
                    var fetch =
                    "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
                    " <entity name='xxx_billingaccount'>" +
                    "   <attribute name='xxx_billingaccountid' />" +
                    "   <attribute name='xxx_name' />" +
                    "   <attribute name='statecode' />" +
                    "   <attribute name='xxx_xid' />" +
                    "   <order attribute='xxx_name' descending='false' />" +
                    "   <filter type='and'>" +
                    "       <condition attribute='xxx_xid' operator='eq' value='" + xId + "' />" +
                    "   </filter>" +
                    " </entity>" +
                    "</fetch>";

                    // Columns to display in the custom view (make sure to include these in the fetch query).
                    var layout = "<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='xxx_name' select='1' icon='0' preview='1'>" +
                    "  <row name='result' id='xxx_billingaccountid'>" +
                    "    <cell name='xxx_name' width='150' />" +
                    "    <cell name='statecode' width='150' />" +
                    "    <cell name='xxx_xid' width='150' />" +
                    "  </row>" +
                    "</grid>";

                    SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.displayFilteredLookupView(gridTypeCode, gridControl, fetch, layout, "Filtered by Customer ID Billing Accounts");
                },
                SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.errorHandler);
```

---

```
displayFilteredLookupView: function (gridTypeCode, gridControl, fetch, layout, viewName) {

        var viewId = "{3D02B064-4D8D-4E7C-B919-965D5D2C225D}";
        var relName = gridControl.GetParameter("relName"),
            roleOrd = gridControl.GetParameter("roleOrd");

        // Creates the custom view object.
        var customView = {
            fetchXml: fetch,
            id: viewId,
            layoutXml: layout,
            name: viewName,
            recordType: gridTypeCode,
            Type: 0
        };

        // Pops the lookup window with our view injected.
        var lookupItems = LookupObjects(null, "multi", gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView], null, null, null, null, null, null, 1);

        // Once the lookup window is closed, we need the parent record ID and ETC before associating selected records.
        if (lookupItems && lookupItems.items.length > 0) {
            var parent = GetParentObject(),
                parentId = parent.id,
                parentTypeCode = parent.objectTypeCode;

            //associates the selected records 
            AssociateObjects(parentTypeCode, parentId, gridTypeCode, lookupItems, IsNull(roleOrd) || roleOrd == 2, "", relName);
        }

    },
```

When I was searching path to resolve this issue I find one link http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/119416/248998.aspx. This is very worse for our project.

Maybe anyone can help me with this issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your `LookupObjects` function to `LookupObjectsWithCallback` function:

```
LookupObjectsWithCallback(callbackReference, null, "multi", gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView], null, null, null, null, null, null, 1);
```

And invoke it in the code like this:

```
   displayFilteredLookupView: function (gridTypeCode, gridControl, fetch, layout, viewName) {

        var viewId = "{3D02B064-4D8D-4E7C-B919-965D5D2C225D}";
        var relName = gridControl.GetParameter("relName"),
            roleOrd = gridControl.GetParameter("roleOrd");

        // Creates the custom view object.
        var customView = {
            fetchXml: fetch,
            id: viewId,
            layoutXml: layout,
            name: viewName,
            recordType: gridTypeCode,
            Type: 0
        };
        // Get all necessary parameters, that you want to pass into your callbackReference function.
        SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.callbackReference.gridTypeCode = gridTypeCode;
        SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.callbackReference.relName = relName;
        SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.callbackReference.roleOrd = roleOrd;

        // Pops the lookup window with our view injected.
        LookupObjectsWithCallback(SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.callbackReference, null, "multi", gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView], null, null, null, null, null, null, 1);                
    }
```

Where your `SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.callbackReference` is an object with properties `callback`, `gridTypeCode`, `roleOrd`, `relName`:

```
 callbackReference: {

    callback: function (lookupItems) {

        // Once the lookup window is closed, we need the parent record ID and ETC before associating selected records.        
        if (lookupItems && lookupItems.items.length > 0) {
            var parent = GetParentObject(),
                parentId = parent.id,
                parentTypeCode = parent.objectTypeCode;

            //associates the selected records 
            AssociateObjects(parentTypeCode, parentId, SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.callbackReference.gridTypeCode, lookupItems, IsNull(SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.callbackReference.roleOrd) || SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.callbackReference.roleOrd == 2, "", SDK.Entity.BillingAccount.callbackReference.relName);
        }
    },
    gridTypeCode: null,
    roleOrd: null,
    relName: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make the above recommendation to work. I think it's my lack of understanding of how to define object 'callbackReference'. When I paste the code as is documented above, Visual Studio complains. Below is the code, which did not work.

```
var locAssocObjAction1 = {

    callback: function (lookupItems) {

        //debugger;
        // Once the lookup window is closed, we need the parent record ID and ETC before associating selected records.        
        if (lookupItems && lookupItems.items.length > 0) {

            var parent = GetParentObject(),
                parentId = parent.id,
                parentTypeCode = parent.objectTypeCode;

            //associates the selected records 
            AssociateObjects(parentTypeCode, parentId, params.gridTypeCode, lookupItems, IsNull(roleOrd) || roleOrd == 2, "", relName);

        }
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Message on alert dialog", function () { });
    }
}

//pops the lookup window with our view injected
LookupObjectsWithCallback(locAssocObjAction1, null, "multi", params.gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]);
```

As a workaround, I found the following solution:

http://www.magnetismsolutions.co.nz/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2014/04/21/filter-n-n-add-existing-lookup-dynamics-crm-2013

The main difference between the above recommendation and Paul Niewelaar's is the following

```
var callbackRef = Mscrm.Utilities.createCallbackFunctionObject("locAssocObjAction", this, parameters, false);

//pops the lookup window with our view injected
LookupObjectsWithCallback(callbackRef, null, "multi", gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]);
```

}

I'm not sure what the implementation is of 'locAssocObjAction'. However, the N:N association seems to work.

Cheers!